# How to input information given by a user in VBA into an Access Database

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access

I'm new to programming and I've had a look around but I'm not quite sure how to relate the answers I've seen on here to what I need. I am doing an IF function to determine what input I should have in my Access database. I want to be able to take the Inpval from what the user has entered in my subroutine into a table in Access.

Here's my IF function. Basically  what I want is, whenever one of the values below is 'True', I want that value to be placed in a field in my Access table so that I'm able to keep a record of all the valid options.

```
Do Until Keepgoing = False
    Message = InputBox("Please enter the module code you would like to enrol in for Semester 1." & vbCrLf & "A list of all available options for " & Inpval & " can be found on the form." & vbCrLf & "(Enter a blank value to exit)")

If Message = "" Then
    Keepgoing = False
    MsgBox "Blank input entered, terminating program."
    Exit Sub
End If

If Message = "SBC120" Then
    Count1 = Count1 + 20
    BP = BP + 1
    BP1 = "Business Programming 1"
ElseIf Message = "SBC110" Then
    Count1 = Count1 + 20
    IB = IB + 1
    IB1 = "International Business 1"
ElseIf Message = "SBC130" Then
    Select Case Inpval
        Case "HRM"
            MsgBox "Sorry, you cannot select Management Science (SBC130) while on the " & Inpval & " programme." & vbCrLf & "See the list of modules available to your programme." & vbCrLf & "Once you are ready to continue, click the 'Return to Form' button and restart the process.", 16, "Module Criteria Not Satisfied"
            DoCmd.OpenReport "HRMModsSem1Rpt", acViewReport
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    Count1 = Count1 + 20
    Response1 = Response1 + 1
    MS1 = "Management Sciences 1"
ElseIf Message = "SBC010" Then
    Count1 = Count1 + 10
    PreReq1 = InputBox("Warning, you have selected Change Management (SBC010) as one of your modules." & vbCrLf & "This can only be selected if you studied Business Transformation (SBB020) in Year 2." & vbCrLf & "If you have not done so, please type 'No'.", "Change Management Prerequisite")
    Select Case PreReq1
        Case "No", "NO", "no", "nO", "N", "n"
            MsgBox "Sorry, because you have not studied Business Transformation (SBB020)," & vbCrLf & "You do not satisfy the selection critera. Please try again.", 16, "Prerequisite Module Not Selected."
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    CM1 = "Change Management"
ElseIf Message = "SBC020" Then
    Count1 = Count1 + 10
    Response3 = Response3 + 1
    BPlan1 = "Business Planning"
ElseIf Message = "SBC030" Then
    Count1 = Count1 + 10
    SBI1 = "Small Business Issues"
ElseIf Message = "SBC040" Then
    Select Case Inpval
        Case "HRM"
            MsgBox "Sorry, you cannot select Decision Analysis (SBC040) while on the " & Inpval & " programme." & vbCrLf & "See the list of modules available to your programme." & vbCrLf & "Once you are ready to continue, click the 'Return to Form' button and restart the process.", 16, "Module Criteria Not Satisfied"
            DoCmd.OpenReport "HRMModsSem1Rpt", acViewReport
            Exit Sub
        Case "AM"
            MsgBox "Sorry, you cannot select Decision Analysis (SBC040) while on the " & Inpval & " programme." & vbCrLf & "See the list of modules available to your programme." & vbCrLf & "Once you are ready to continue, click the 'Return to Form' button and restart the process.", 16, "Module Criteria Not Satisfied"
            DoCmd.OpenReport "AMModsSem1Rpt", acViewReport
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    Count1 = Count1 + 10
    Response1 = Response1 + 1
    DA1 = "Decision Analysis"
ElseIf Message = "SBC150" Then
    MgmtDiss = InputBox("You have selected Management Dissertation (SBC150) as one of your modules." & vbCrLf & "Please specify the number of credits this module will provide for this semester (10 or 20).", "Management Dissertation Module")
    Select Case MgmtDiss
        Case "10", "Ten", "ten", "TEN"
            Count1 = Count1 + 10
            MDCred = 10
            MsgBox "Thank you, it is required that you select Management Dissertation (SBC150) in your Semester 2 options." & vbCrLf & "This will make up " & 30 - MDCred & " of your Semester 2 credits."
        Case "20", "Twenty", "twenty", "TWENTY"
            Count1 = Count1 + 20
            MDCred = 20
            MsgBox "Thank you, it is required that you select Management Dissertation (SBC150) in your Semester 2 options." & vbCrLf & "This will make up " & 30 - MDCred & " of your Semester 2 credits."
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect value, please enter '10' or '20'.", 32
    End Select
    MD = ("Management Dissertation" & MDCred & (30 - MDCred))
Else: MsgBox "Input not recognised, please enter a correct Module Code.", 32
End If
```

Comment: Please do not use input boxes, use forms.

Comment: In addition to the learning suggested by @Steve W - I would be tempted to list the available options in a combo box , with any additional information you need from those choices as hidden extra column. 
.
You can then refer to values based on the users choices and don't need to worry about invalid selections at all, this would keep you code much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to the wonderful world of programming!  There are a couple ways of recording data based on the user's input.  You can either do it through a SQL statement or through the usage of a record set.  As you have figured out already, the more you learn in programming the more you realize you don't know.  Here are a couple of links to get you started.  My recommendation would be to work with the record set first before venturing out into the world of SQL.

Adding and changing data via record sets:

http://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/

Adding and changing data via SQL:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp